# owl-carousel not working in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

`responsive` property doesn't seem to have an effect. In desktop version it is working fine, but on mobile device it still shows the same number of items as in desktop.

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:5,
    nav:false,
    responsiveClass:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2500,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have responsive meta tag in ```head``` of page: ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```?

Comment: yes I did it but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, maybe you did not include responsive meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Seems to be working fine with the code you added, maybe some css that is overwriting this somehow?

```js
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:5,
    nav:false,
    responsiveClass:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:2500,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.owl-carousel .item h4 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>6</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>7</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>8</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>9</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>10</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>11</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>12</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

These are two ways I found:

1-you have to set minimum-scale and maximum-scale of viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

2- Add following option to js:

```
responsiveBaseElement: 'body'
```

Comment: Thx! responsiveBaseElement: 'body' is working for me)